# How to iterate through data table columns in R to graph them with plotly?

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to figure out how to iterate through columns in a data table in R to graph in plotly. Not sure how to do this. Below is the code:

```
library(data.table)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

month_date = c("2019-01-01", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-03")
num_cars = c(100,201,168)
num_planes = c(10,15,17)

master = data.frame(month_date, num_cars, num_planes)

names(master)[2:3] %>%
  lapply(function(z){
    
    plot_ly(master, 
            x = ~month_date, 
            y = z, 
            type = 'scatter', 
            mode = 'lines')
    
  })
```

Appreciate the help.

**A WORKAROUND**

I can get this to work below but I don't love using the index. If anyone has something more elegant, would be good:

```
2:3 %>%
  lapply(function(z){
    print(z)
    plot_ly(master, 
            x = ~month_date, 
            y = ~master[,z], 
            type = 'scatter', 
            mode = 'lines')
    
  })
```

Comment: I am getting: Error in map(names(master)[-1], ~plot_ly(master, x = ~month_date, y = ~rlang::sym(.y),  : 
  could not find function "map"

Comment: I updated with some solutions that are working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option with `for` loop

```
plst <- vector('list', length(master)-1)
names(plst) <- names(master)[-1]
for(nm in names(plst)) {
   plst[[nm]] <- plot_ly(master, x = ~ month_date, y = get(nm),
        type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')
 }
```

-check the plots

```
plst$num_cars
plst$num_planes
```

---

Or using the OP's code, just change the 'z'  with `get(z)`

```
names(master)[2:3] %>%
   lapply(function(z){
     
     plot_ly(master, 
             x = ~month_date, 
             y = get(z), # // or it can be master[[z]]
             type = 'scatter', 
             mode = 'lines')
     
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using `subplot` to combine plots after getting the data in long format.

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

master %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -month_date) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  group_map(~ plot_ly(data=., x = ~month_date, 
                      y = ~value, type = "scatter", mode="lines")) %>%
  subplot(nrows = 1, shareX = TRUE, shareY=FALSE)
```

[image]